# Determining the number of Geom(1/2) r.v.'s that can fit within N trials (Application to St. Petersburg Paradox)

Tags: probability

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d Geom(1/2) r.v's. And let N be a fixed natural number. Let $L_N$ be the r.v. that describes the number of $X_i$ that can fit within N trials, i.e. I am interested in the numbers $n$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i=N$ and the corresponding probabilities P($L_N=n$)$=P(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i=N)$. As a concrete example, consider an $N$ length sequence of coin flips. The St. Petersburg game unfolds by flipping a fair coin until it lands on tails for the first time. Given $N$ coin flips, I'd like to determine how many St. Petersburg games I can expect to find embedded in this sequence of flips.

My first thought was to interpret $L_N$ as a convolution of geometric random variables, but this is not accurate since the number of r.v.'s in the sum is not fixed, and is precisely what I am trying to determine. So far, I know: $P(L_N=0)=(1/2)^N=P(L_N=N)$ since the LHS is the event that we have flipped H for all N flips, and hence no completed game is found inside the sequence, and the RHS is the event that we have flipped T for all N flips. Also, $P(L_N=K)=0$ $\forall K>N$ since it is impossible to have more games than flips. My hunch is that that $E(L_N)$ would grow at a linear rate with respect to N since $E(X_i)=2$ for all $i$. Any advice or input is appreciated.

Comment: By your description it's possible that $L_N$ is undefined. For instance, if $X_1=X_2=2$ and $N=3$, then there is no $n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=N$. Perhaps instead you want to define $L_N=n$ to mean $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq N$ but $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}X_i>N$? I.e., $L_N =\max\{n \mid \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq N\}$?

Comment: Yes, good point. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're going for (in particular note the valid concerns of kccu in the comments; I assume you want a $\max$ as suggested), the variable you seek has a binomial distribution.

To illustrate why, suppose your geometric variables are based on a coin flip, and a "success" that ends the game is heads. If your games within the first ten coin throws are

$$\begin{array}{r} TT\mathbf H \\ \mathbf H \\ TTT\mathbf H \\ \mathbf H \\ \mathbf H \end{array}$$
you could stack these end to end to obtain
$$TT\mathbf H \mathbf H TTT \mathbf H \mathbf H \mathbf H$$
and note that what's really relevant is how many game-terminating events (i.e. heads) have occurred within the first 10 throws. The expected number of these would then be $Np$, where $p$ is the probability of success; in your case, $N/2$.